# Twisting and stopping and slowly untwisting in the gusting rain,

Tags: sentence-meaning

> On the naked bank between the yard and humming river’s edge, a pack of hounds pads back and forth, whimpering with cold and brute frustration, whimpering and barking at an object that dangles out of their reach, over the water, twisting and untwisting, swaying stiffly at the end of a line tied to the tip of a large fir pole . . . jutting out of a top-story window.
>
> Twisting and stopping and slowly untwisting in the gusting rain, eight or ten feet above the flood’s current, a human arm, tied at the wrist, ( just the arm; look) disappearing downward at the frayed shoulder where an invisible dancer performs twisting pirouettes for an enthralled audience

Quoted from "SOMETIMES A GREAT NOTION" by Ken Kesey

I don't get this scene. is the arm severed and tied to a pole sticking out of a window?

Comment: And [that's probably the arm mentioned](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0067774/mediaviewer/rm2830714880/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the first para, the severed arm is tied to a pole sticking out of a window.

I think maybe the dancer is invisible because only the arm remains. *He is just imagining what the dancer **would be doing** based on the movement he observes of the arm. Pretty gross, huh? Kesey is not exactly a teddy bear*.

He's imaging the dancer's body based on his observing the arm's movements in the wind.

Comment: It's attached to a boat. Hank attaches Henry’s severed arm to the boat pulling the logs in such a way that the hand gives the middle finger to the townspeople watching him go by.

Comment: 50 years since I read this,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right. Not getting anything.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean it was not enough to get to you. We have to find another way.